# Can I make iconify-window binding work when minimize using window manager

Tags: emacs, window-manager

I can bind a function to run when Emacs iconifies a frame

```
(defun my-handle-iconify-frame()
  ;; I actually do something more useful than this...
  (message "my-handle-iconify-frame")
)
(define-key special-event-map [iconify-frame] (function my-handle-iconify-frame))
```

This runs my `my-handle-iconify-frame` function when I use `M-x iconify-frame` or a key binding that calls that function.

However, it does not **run** when I use the iconify icon (-) in the window frame.

I also tried adding before advice on `iconify-frame` but that also is not called when I iconify a frame via the window frame icon.

Is there some other hook or binding where I can set window manager event handlers?

I'm running GNU Emacs 24.2.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin, NS apple-appkit-1038.36) of 2012-08-27 on bob.porkrind.org

Comment: It sounds like a problem with your particular window mgr (or between it and Emacs). On MS Windows (XP, 7, etc.) it works for me to do exactly what you tried: `(define-key special-event-map [iconify-frame] 'my-command)`. I use that in library [`thumb-frm.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/thumb-frm.el) to "thumbify" instead of iconify Emacs frames. (See [Fisheye With Thumbs](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FisheyeWithThumbs).)

Comment: This is AskDifferent - I'm running on a MacBook Air ; emacs reports the window-system is 'ns; system-type is 'darwinSo perhaps it is a Mac port problem.

Comment: It might be a porting problem. But it might also be difficult or impossible to DTRT with that window system. Dunno. You can try reporting it to Emacs Dev: `M-x report-emacs-bug` -- or to whomever ported it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this. I must make the function (interactive):

```
(defun my-handle-iconify-frame()
  (interactive)
  ;; I actually do something more useful than this...
  (message "in my-handle-iconify-frame")
)
```

obvious in retrospect, since it is run through a key binding, not as a hook function.